# OpenGL per pixel lighting in fixed function pipeline

Tags: opengl, lighting

Is it possible to enable per-pixel lighting (so that I can have nice specular highlights on low tessellated surfaces) in the OpenGL fixed function pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do this is using precomputed cubemaps. The fixed function pipeline interpolates colors and texture coordinates across polygons. Color is useless but the texturing can be used.

It won't be position-dependent, but you can precalculate cubemaps for areas and blend between them using BLEND_ADD and drawing it twice with both cubemaps you're LERPing between.

Comment: So I can conclude that per pixel evaluation of the lighting equation is not possible in the opengl fixed function pipeline.

Comment: false. Diffuse is possible (not sure about specular), but in opengl 1 there is a DOT3 extension for use with the texture environment, or you could use ARB assembly.